# Good video on separating eggs

Tags: eggs, resources

Could anyone point me to a good video on cracking an egg and then separating the white and the yolk?  I need to improve my technique.  For every few eggs that I crack I end up with little bits of egg shell in the white that I then have to pick out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I find the site [startcooking.com](http://www.startcooking.com) particularly useful for some quick videos that are narrated clearly, photographed neatly, and generally are better in quality than those found on Youtube.

Here is the video at that site: http://startcooking.com/video/295/Crack-and-Separate-an-Egg

That said, there are many such videos on Youtube that might be useful also:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-OwbEy-Vxk
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yAGX-54iR30
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=04jY7A1yy_g

Answer (score 6):

Just crack the egg and empty the contents into the slightly closed fingers of your hand. Spread the fingers a little over a bowl, to let the white run out, place the yoke in a separate bowl.

Comment: I don't have edit privileges yet... you definitely want to say "bowl" instead of "bowel." Definitely.

Comment: That's what happens when English is not ones native language. Thanks for the heads-up

Comment: No worries, just wanted to help. :)

Answer (score 2):

I accidentally found a slick way **to separate the egg yolk from the white: before cracking, shake the egg like crazy.** I expected the egg to to be scrambled after doing this, but when I cracked it open into the frying pan, the yolk was intact! The yolk just slipped away from the egg white, frying completely separately.

---

*Related trivia: you can use this technique to make an egg stand upright on its own.*

Comment: How did you _accidentally_ shake the egg like crazy?

Comment: @Tim: I didn't actually shake the egg^^ I was demonstrating something to my middle-school tutoring student, and he was goofing off with the egg.

Answer (score 1):

Check THIS one out! It went viral for good reason - I've tried it, it works just like in the video! She slightly squeezes a plastic water bottle and presses the opening against the top of the yolk, then releases the pressure on the bottle. The resulting vacuum sucks the clean yolk (no white at all) into the bottle. Another squeeze and the yolk is deposited in another bowl. She picks up and deposits the same yolk repeatedly. It's headshaking - Why didn't *I* think of that?! No more eggy fingers.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uz2Vnp5ZW4c

Comment: You might summarize the technique to add value to the answer...

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ --Done