# How to remove bits of egg shell from a cracked egg?

Tags: eggs

Sometimes when I crack eggs, I end up with a bit of shell in the egg.  How can I easily get the shell out, as it always seems to evade my fingers?

Comment: A [similar question](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/640/good-video-on-separating-eggs/646#646) had an answer that points to videos on how do crack and separate eggs.  The videos demonstrate how to use one of the half shells to scoop up any pieces that fall inside.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use part of the shell you just cracked to scoop it up; it will attract the broken bit.

Also, if you frequently end up with bits of shell in your eggs, you should revise your cracking technique. Eggs should be cracked on a flat surface (countertop or plate) not a sharper surface like the edge of a bowl.

Comment: the "cracking on a flat surface" tip is interesting -- I'll try that next time

Comment: Tried the "cracking on a flat surface" tip, it definetly works better than cracking on a bowl's edge.

Answer (score 5):

If the egg is going to get mixed up anyway, go ahead and mix it with the shell in there. Then, pour it through a colander (with a bowl underneath, of course).

- It doesn't work well to use a fine wire mesh colander; the egg won't go through it.
- Even with a plastic colander, you'll still lose a bit of egg.

Also, sometimes just pouring the egg from one bowl to another leaves the bit of shell behind.

Answer (score 4):

I tend to just stab right down with my finger and trap the shell on the bottom of the bowl, then slide out.

But yeah.. refine your cracking technique and you'll find this happening less and less. On average I crack 65 eggs every few days (all at once) when making creme brulee and a couple other things at work. Sheer blinding repetition will make your cracking skills much, much better, trust me.

Comment: +1 for practise: My sister (a chef) can crack eggs one handed, and each one is perfect, no shell fragments

Comment: Does she do the big stack? I play a game with myself when cracking a whole flat of eggs: I try to stack all the shells into a tall and precarious tower.